# How can I convert a string into a list of individual character tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I'm trying to take something like:
input = "hello world"

And get the following result:
[('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'), ('w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')]

I was able to split the input into individual words, and then the words into a list of characters, and then the list into a tuple...but they aren't separated by word like they are in the example.

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")
word_list = sentence.split()
print(word_list)

chars = []
for x in sentence:
    chars.append(x)
print(chars)

tuple_list = tuple(word_list)
print(type(tuple_list))
```

The code above prints
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
and not 
[('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'), ('w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go by your original attempt.

```
word_list = sentence.split() # ['hello', 'world']
```

We have a list of two words, however in your attempt, you iterate over the original input from the user as opposed to the word list that you made. So the code should become:

```
chars = []
for x in word_list:
    chars.append(tuple(x))

print(chars)
# [('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'), ('w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd')]
```

Comment: Ah, okay! This one makes a lot more sense to me. I'm just starting with Python and 'map' (from another response) was unfamiliar to me.

Comment: `map` just maps a function to each element of an iterable, hence the name, so in that case its essentially applying `tuple` to each element of `word_list`, hope that makes sense @AmandaTreutler

Comment: That's handy! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can split the string and map the sub-strings to the tuple constructor:

```
s = "hello world"
list(map(tuple, s.split()))
```

Comment: That did it!! And it's so efficient. Thank you so much; I really appreciate it! :)